# What are extracellular matrix pathways?

Tags: cell-biology, cancer

I was reading a research paper dealing with acute myeloid leukemia and the term "extracellular matrix pathway" came up. What does it mean? I found literature on extracellular matrix, but I'm not sure what the "pathway" indicates.

Comment: Can you add a link to the paper? This might help.

Comment: @Goldname read this one, http://joe.endocrinology-journals.org/content/209/2/139.full

Comment: Sorry, I can't link it because the paper is not available online yet

Comment: Can you at least [edit] your question and add a paragraph or two of context?